# .NET 6.0 Azure C# Function - How to get Url.Link() helper function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

In our .NET 5.0 windows apps, we have created the concept of a root document that returns links to resources in our API. This way the client can auto discover endpoints.

The logic we have is something like this:

```
        [Route("/api",  Name="GetRoot")]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult getRoot()
        {
            var links = new List<HateoasLink>();
            links.Add(
            new HateoasLink(Url.Link("GetRoot", new { }),
            "self",
            "GET"));

            links.Add(
            new HateoasLink(Url.Link("GetProducts", new { }),
            "products",
            "GET"));

            links.Add(
            new HateoasLink(Url.Link("GetUsers", new { }),
            "users",
            "GET"));

            return Ok(links);
        }
```

The HateoasLink class just looks like this:

```
public class HateoasLink
{
    public string Href { get; private set; }
    public string Rel { get; private set; }
    public string Method { get; private set; }

    public HateoasLink(string href, string rel, string method)
    {
        Href = href;
        Rel = rel; 
        Method = method;
    }
```

I'm trying to do something similar now for an Azure function project - using .NETCore 6.0, functions version 4.  But I can't seem to find the right library that includes similar Url.Link() helper function as is provided by System.Web.Http.Routing.